# HP-Exstream add Barcode in PDF

Tags: pdf, hp-exstream

Does HP-Exstream have functionality to take a PDF file as input and add a barcode to the supplied PDF file?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using placeholder variables, Input the PDFs path from customer driver file to engine (each path cab be separated by customer , then add the BAR CODE wherever you want in the page .

Answer (score 0):

There definitely is a functionality for adding barcode to external PDF - after importing external data content over PDF placeholder variable.

Important to know is if data on the barcode is:

1) directly client related (e.g. client identifiers, business case id etc.)
2) company related (product, language, form type etc.).

For the case 1) you would have to calculate barcode values from client data, in case 2) you may use initialization or (better) reference / auxiliary data file to help you extract desired values to barcode formula. Eventual join of 1) and 2) would mean that client data source (customer driver file) may not be enough for barcode values.

Customer data source for corporate communication usually doesn't provide direct link to PDF in driver file, so init/ref file between your client data and unique PDF file will be needed, should you perform this operation in batch mode.

And small practical advice: barcode values should be positioned and formatted according to scanning (reading) requirements - e.g. values positioning and separation:

```
000FIELD1;FIELD2;FIELD3000
000FIELD1000FIELD2000FIELD3000
```

Answer (score 0):

It possible by adding Barcode on application or page level. Value for populating barcode depends on some value. For example IMB barcode are 31 char which is combination of 5 fields.